# Как расширить кнопки bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как расширить или увеличить кнопки? Код css не робит.

```css
.btn-lg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Block</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row" style = "margin-left:700px; margin-top:200px;margin:display;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button typ ="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg"data-toggle="dropdown">Default</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
          <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class = "divider"></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--
   --><div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class ="btn btn-light"data-toggle="dropdown">Primary</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
          <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class = "divider"></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Где ты объявлял свой css файл?

Comment: не работает ваш css потому что он просто не подключен

Answer (score 0):

Твой css должен быть в коде **ниже** обьявления bootstrap:
- либо в теге `<style></style>`
- либо как подключенный файл.